# Manually publish s3 folder to Cloud front

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I uploaded some files to my S3 bucket, how do I make them available in my Cloud front?

Any idea?

Comment: Are other files in your S3 bucket available, just not the ones you recently uploaded? Or is nothing in the S3 bucket available in CloudFront?

Comment: Those file are available in S3 bucket, but not in Cloud front.

Answer (score 1):

I think this 'getting started' article is what you need: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html

(make sure you correctly set permissions for S3 objects, otherwise CloudFront won't be able to access them)